# Java referencing final variable before is has been initialized

Tags: java, inheritance, final, dynamic-binding

I have this superclass `Creature` and its subclass `Monster`. Now I have this problem of a final variable being referenced without it being initialized.

```
public class Creature {

    private int protection;

    public Creature(int protection) {
        setProtection(protection);
    }

    public void setProtection(int p) {
        if(!canHaveAsProtection(p))
            throw new Exception();
        this.protection = p;
    }

    public boolean canHaveAsProtection(int p) {
        return p>0;
    }
}
```

and the subclass:

```
public class Monster extends Creature {

    private final int maxProtection;

    public Monster(int protection) {
        super(protection);
        this.maxProtection = protection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canHaveAsProtection(int p) {
        return p>0 && p<maxProtection
    } 
}
```

As you can see, when I initialize a new `Monster`, it will call the constructor of `Creature` with `super(protection)`. In the constructor of `Creature`, the method `canHaveAsProtection(p)` is called, which by dynamic binding takes the overwritten one in `Monster`. However, this overwritten version uses the final variable `maxProtection` which hasn't been initialized yet...
How can I solve this?

Comment: In the code sample Monster is not subclassing Creature.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Aren't you requiring that `maxProtection < maxProtection` here?

Comment: No, you're requiring the given protection in the constructor of Monster  is smaller than maxProtection which still has to be set.

Comment: Yes, but `maxProtection` will be set to `protection` afterwards, so the logic is as I describe, but with the two steps reordered.

Comment: try  if(!this.canHaveAsProtection(p))

Answer (score 1):

Some points:

- only Monster cares about a max value, so only it should know about this concept
- all Creatures must have a protection > 0
- don't defer range checking to a separate method
- the upper and lower bound checking doesn't need to be in the same place
- use the Decorator Pattern to solve the problem

Putting this all together, your code should look like this:

```
public class Creature {

    private int protection;

    protected Creature() {
    }

    public Creature(int protection) {
        setProtection(protection);
    }

    public void setProtection(int p) {
        if (p < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.protection = p;
    }
}

public class Monster extends Creature {

    private final int maxProtection;

    private Monster(int protection) {
        this.maxProtection = protection;
        setProtection(protection);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProtection(int p) {
        if (protection > maxProtection)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        super.setProtection(p);;
    }

    public static Monster create(int protection) {
        Monster monster = new Monster(protection);
        monster.validate();
        return monster;
    }
}
```

You haven't shown what the `validate()` method dies, but if it's only needed for protection checking, I would delete it and the static factory method and make the constructor of Monster public.

Answer (score 0):

`Monster` does not extend `Creature` in the code you posted.

If it does, I see no reason for `Monster` to have a final variable.  `Creature` ought to have the final variable, and `Monster` should simply access it.  If there needs to be a max value validation for protection, it seems to me that all `Creature` instances ought to have it.

Push it up from the `Monster` to `Creature` and you're fine.  You should have two arguments in the `Creature` constructor: `protection` and `maxProtection`.  Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if `maxProtection < 0` or `protection` falls outside the range `0..maxProtection`.

Comment: It's just a little part of the whole code which is more complex. The bottom line is: there's no reason for the variable maxProtection to be in the subclass. But if it's the only solution...

Comment: I think it should be pushed up to the super class and made part of its contract.

Comment: All the other subclasses of Creature also have the variable maxProtection then, which is of no use for them. Is that the proper way?

Comment: I disagree - I think it is of use to them.  It seems to me to be part of the contract for setting protection level, which should be true for all Creatures.  I disagree with your thinking and design.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with your initialisation chain.

The child class must be fully I initialised before the parent can be initialised.

Currently, it looks like this...

> Monster->Creature->Creature#setProtection->Monster#canHaveAsProtection
>   ...

where maxProtextion hasn't been initialised, because the Creature constrcutor hasn't returned.

A solution would be to defer the initialisation some how, perhaps in a init method that the constructors can call

Answer (score 0):

It is really a bad practice to call public methods in constructor, especially when you expect to subclass it.

Your class should be solid and initialize it's state independently.
I think you should set `protection` variable explicitly in constructor:

```
public Creature(int protection) {
    this.protection = protection;
}
```

If you really want to validate your parameters in constructor then extract common functionality to private methods:

```
public Creature(int protection) {
    Assert.isTrue(isProtectionValid(p));
    this.protection = protection;
}

private static boolean isProtectionValid(int p) {
    return p > 0;
}

public boolean canHaveAsProtection(int p) {
    return isProtectionValid(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the reasons mentioned in the other answers, do:

```
public Creature(int protection) {
    this.protection = protection;
}

public Monster(int protection) {
    super(protection + 1);
    this.maxProtection = protection;
}
```

That correction `+ 1` seems to be your intended logic because of the `< maxProtection`.

Answer (score 0):

How about you override the set protection en set the max first en than call on super set protection.

```
    @override
   public void setProtection(int p) {
        this.maxProtection = p;
    super.setProtection(p);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried this one and did it work for you? I am just wondering!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call public methods in a constructor. Instead you could change constructor modifier to protected/private and use factory methods in which validation is called:

```
public class Creature {
    private int protection;

    protected Creature(int protection) {
        this.protection = protection;
    }

    public void setProtection(int protection) {
        if (!canHaveAsProtection(protection))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.protection = protection;
    }

    public boolean canHaveAsProtection(int protection) {
        return protection > 0;
    }

    protected void validate() {
        if (!canHaveAsProtection(this.protection))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public static Creature create(int protection) {
        Creature creature = new Creature(protection);
        creature.validate();
        return creature;
    }
}
```

And `Monster`:

```
public class Monster extends Creature {

    private final int maxProtection;

    private Monster(int protection) {
        super(protection);
        this.maxProtection = protection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canHaveAsProtection(int p) {
        // I changed '<' to '<=' because '<' wouldn't work anyway
        return p > 0 && p <= maxProtection;
    }

    public static Monster create(int protection) {
        Monster monster = new Monster(protection);
        monster.validate();
        return monster;
    }
}
```